# Have \underbrace lead to an arrow pointing towards expression (not replace underbrace)

Tags: equations

I have a long expression coming from using `\underbrace`. It is causing the equation to look, for lack of a better adjective, strange. Here is the entire equation:

```
\begin{equation}
  \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\dm\phi\dn\phi = \frac{1}{2}\left[
    \underbrace{g^{0\nu}\d_0\phi\dn\phi}_{g^{00}\d_0\phi\d_0\phi+
      \cancel{g^{01}}\d_0\phi\d_1\phi+\cancel{g^{02}}\d_0\phi\d_2\phi+
      \cancel{g^{03}}\d_0\phi\d_3\phi}+
    g^{1\nu}\d_1\phi\dn\phi+g^{2\nu}\d_2\phi\dn\phi
    + g^{3\nu}\d_3\phi\dn\phi\right]
\end{equation}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image: Equation]

Is it possible to have an arrow come from the underbrace towards somewhere else under the equation so the main equation does not have to accommodate for the length of the expression beneath the underbrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\mathclap` (or `\mathrlap`) from the [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}

\newcommand\dn{\mathrm{d}\, n}
\newcommand\dm{\mathrm{d}\, m}
\def\d{\mathrm{d}}% Don't do this

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\dm\phi\dn\phi = \frac{1}{2}\bigl[\,
    \underbrace{g^{0\nu}\d_0\phi\dn\phi}_{\mathclap{g^{00}\d_0\phi\d_0\phi+
      \cancel{g^{01}}\d_0\phi\d_1\phi+\cancel{g^{02}}\d_0\phi\d_2\phi+
      \cancel{g^{03}}\d_0\phi\d_3\phi}}+
    g^{1\nu}\d_1\phi\dn\phi+g^{2\nu}\d_2\phi\dn\phi
    + g^{3\nu}\d_3\phi\dn\phi\bigr]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\dm\phi\dn\phi = \frac{1}{2}\bigl[\,
    \underbrace{g^{0\nu}\d_0\phi\dn\phi}_{\mathrlap{g^{00}\d_0\phi\d_0\phi+
      \cancel{g^{01}}\d_0\phi\d_1\phi+\cancel{g^{02}}\d_0\phi\d_2\phi+
      \cancel{g^{03}}\d_0\phi\d_3\phi}}+
    g^{1\nu}\d_1\phi\dn\phi+g^{2\nu}\d_2\phi\dn\phi
    + g^{3\nu}\d_3\phi\dn\phi\bigr]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I didn't had the original definitions for `\dn` and `\dm` so I provided some definitions for the example. From your code, it seems that you are also redefining `\d` (as I did in my example to reproduce the result); please choose a different name, since `\d` is an already existing command.

Comment: Probably he/she has `\renewcommand{\d}{\partial}`  
`\newcommand{\dm}{\partial_{\mu}}`  
`\newcommand{\dn}{\partial_{\nu}}`

Comment: @karlkoeller probably, yes, except for `\renewcommand\d{...}`; he must have `\def\d{...}`; otherwise, an error is triggered.

Comment: I tried the above MWE with `\renewcommand{\d}{\partial}` and I have no errors. Why should it occur?

Comment: @karlkoeller sorry; I thought you had `\newcommand\d{...}`. Using `\nenewcommand\d{...}` doesn't produce errors, but it's not correct, since `\d` is a basic command to produce an accent (a little dot below the argument).

Comment: I have this: `\def\d{\partial}
\def\dm{\partial_{\mu}}
\def\dn{\partial_{\nu}}` with no errors.

Comment: @dougphy as I said, the problem is not errors. `\d` is an already defined command to produce a special accent. With your definition for `\d` you are overwriting an existing command. I suggest you to not do that, anc choose another name for your command.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks for pointing that out